# DEFAULT column value support in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

Does CockroachDB support default values for columns in its tables? Does it allow default values to be function values (e.g. `current_date()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set DEFAULT values using the DEFAULT constraint, which CockroachDB has documented [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/default-value.html).

It also supports setting the default value as a function, e.g. to insert the date that a write occurred.

You would create a table with such a default column like:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_log (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    date_purchased DATE DEFAULT current_date()
);
```

Then all inserts to the table that don't specify the `date_purchased` column will have the column automatically populated with the return value of `current_date()` at the time of the insert.